# 'HTTP Error 403: SSL is required' on using Ubuntu shell

Tags: python, ubuntu, starcluster

So I am manually installing StarCluster on my PC using instructions from [here](http://star.mit.edu/cluster/docs/latest/installation.html) but am getting this error:

urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBtq6.png)

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starcluster's official [python project page](https://pypi.org/project/StarCluster/) says it does not support Python3. It supports Python2.6 and Python2.7

The package can be installed using pip. There are some prerequisites for this.

`$ sudo apt-get install build-essential python python-dev python-openssl`

Once these packages are installed you should be able to install StarCluster.

`$ sudo pip install StarCluster`

If you are working in a python virtual environment. You don't need sudo

`$ pip install StarCluster`